# undefined reference to boost::system::system_category when using BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB building for android using QtCreator

Tags: android, c++, boost

Boost doesn't really care about android development, so I decided that instead of desperately trying to get static libraries of boost for android, I'll just build boost sources along with my program.

I added this define for my build:

```
DEFINES += BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB
```

And I added library and `.cpp` files:

```
 boost155/libs/system/src/error_code.cpp \
 boost155/libs/thread/src/pthread/once.cpp \
 boost155/libs/thread/src/pthread/once_atomic.cpp \
 boost155/libs/thread/src/pthread/thread.cpp \
 boost155/libs/thread/src/future.cpp \
 boost155/libs/thread/src/tss_null.cpp \
 boost155/libs/iostreams/src/file_descriptor.cpp \
 boost155/libs/iostreams/src/gzip.cpp \
 boost155/libs/iostreams/src/mapped_file.cpp \
 boost155/libs/iostreams/src/zlib.cpp \
 boost155/libs/chrono/src/chrono.cpp \
 boost155/libs/chrono/src/process_cpu_clocks.cpp \
 boost155/libs/chrono/src/thread_clock.cpp \
 boost155/libs/date_time/src/gregorian/date_generators.cpp \
 boost155/libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_month.cpp \
 boost155/libs/date_time/src/gregorian/greg_weekday.cpp \
 boost155/libs/date_time/src/gregorian/gregorian_types.cpp \
 boost155/libs/date_time/src/posix_time/posix_time_types.cpp
 boost155/libs/filesystem/src/codecvt_error_category.cpp \
 boost155/libs/filesystem/src/operations.cpp \
 boost155/libs/filesystem/src/path.cpp \
 boost155/libs/filesystem/src/path_traits.cpp \
 boost155/libs/filesystem/src/portability.cpp \
 boost155/libs/filesystem/src/unique_path.cpp \
 boost155/libs/filesystem/src/utf8_codecvt_facet.cpp \
```

The header files get included the same way as with normal PC build:

```
 INCLUDEPATH += ../libs/boost155/
```

The project **compiles without errors**, but during the **linking** I get linker errors:

```
./libs/boost155/boost/system/error_code.hpp:323: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::system_category()'
../libs/boost155/boost/thread/exceptions.hpp:51: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::system_category()'
../libs/boost155/boost/asio/error.hpp:224: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::system_category()'
../libs/boost155/boost/system/error_code.hpp:222: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::generic_category()'
../libs/boost155/boost/system/error_code.hpp:223: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::generic_category()'
../libs/boost155/boost/system/error_code.hpp:224: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::system_category()'
../libs/boost155/boost/chrono/detail/inlined/posix/chrono.hpp:59: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::throws'
../libs/boost155/boost/chrono/detail/inlined/posix/chrono.hpp:113: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::throws'
../libs/boost155/boost/chrono/detail/inlined/posix/process_cpu_clocks.hpp:118: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::throws'
../libs/boost155/boost/chrono/detail/inlined/posix/process_cpu_clocks.hpp:194: error: undefined reference to 'boost::system::throws'
```

What `.cpp` am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

`BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` just tells the headers not to link (`#pragma lib(...)`). Of *course* this leads to unresolved externals if you use them.

I'd suggest you should consider linking to the static libraries instead of manually selecting some cpp files.

Out on a limb, perhaps you have added the cpp files but they don't actually participate in the build (have you checked?).

Otherwise, perhaps you've been tinkering a bit and also defined `BOOST_ERROR_CODE_HEADER_ONLY` but not in all cases. In that case you would get undefined symbols *even compiling and linking error_code.cpp*. The reason is because that file conditionally compiles some parts.

Comment: I am afraid that there was something wrong with that boost release. I switched to boost 159 (without changing anything else) and it compiled without problems. It's not the first time switching to newer or older boost version fixed weird problems.

Comment: Of course not. I don't know what would make Boost immune to bugs :)

Comment: Feel free to add it as an answer. It could help others in the future (well, as long as people still use the affected versions)

Comment: And also, of course, if boost provided survivable way of building static libs for Android, I'd appreciate it. But so far, I haven't experienced painless build for windows either. My current approach seems to be promising in that aspect that I won't need to deal with all the 64/32bit and other issues for static libs.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by switching to boost 1.59 - this means there was probably something wrong with my 1.55 release.